# pyspark getattr() behavior

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Noticed some strange behavior with PySpark, would appreciate any insights.

Suppose I have an RDD composed of simple elements

```
from collections import namedtuple
Animal = namedtuple('Animal', ('name','age'))
a = Animal('jeff',3)
b = Animal('mike',5)
c = Animal('cathy',5)
rdd=sc.parallelize([a,b,c])
```

Now I'm interested in capturing, in a simple class, the different attributes of that RDD, using for example `rdd.map(lambda s: getattr(s,'name'))` to extract the `name` attribute from each element.

So objects of this class

```
class simple():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
    def get_value(self):
        self.value = rdd.map(lambda s: getattr(s,self.name)).collect()
```

will set their `name` and fetch the corresponding `values` from the RDD.

```
theAges = simple('age')
theAges.get_value()
```

However, this encounters an error that I think centers on the `self.name` in the `lambda` expression. This second class works fine

```
class simple2():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
    def get_value(self):
        n=self.name
        self.value = rdd.map(lambda s: getattr(s,n)).collect()
```

where all I have added is a preceding call `n=self.name` and passed `n` into the `lambda` instead of `self.name`.

So is the problem that we are unable to evaluate `self.name` within the `lambda`? I've created a similar situation (with `self.name` in a `lambda`) in pure python and there's no errors, so I think this is Spark specific.  Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to pyspark being unable to create a closure over the class instance.  Assigning `n` in the `get_value` scope allows Spark to ship off the pickled function including what amounts to an alias to the object attribute. So far, it seems the solution is to just assign class attributes in the function scope (but don't count on them changing!)